# How to determine if a undirected graph is a forest in $\mathcal{O}(|V|)$?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

So how to determine in $\mathcal{O}(|V|)$ if a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a forest?

Hope somebody has an idea.

Comment: how is the graph saved?

Comment: I can't think any possible algorithm that says there is no cycle without having seen all edges

Comment: @JorgeFernández - From your answer below, isn't it sufficient to check the 2nd condition only - "if the graph has cycles?" Why do we need to verify the first condition? I think a graph with cycles will always have edges >= vertices. Please rectify me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graph is saved with adjacency lists you can recover the degree of a vertex in constant time. Using this you can check if $e\leq v-1$ in $\mathcal O(v)$ time. If this is not the case then the graph is not a forest.

Now that we know that $e\leq v-1$ we can explicitly look for cycles using dfse's, and since the number of edges is less than $v$ this has complexity $\mathcal O(v)$.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to check the 2nd condition only - "if the graph has cycles?" Why do we need to verify the first condition? I think a graph with cycles will always have edges >= vertices. Please rectify me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, if you look for cycles first you run the risk of the algorithm being O(E)

Comment: Actually in hindsight this is not true, you can just do a dfs but make sure to exit as soon as a cycle is found.