# Reference for complexity of checking whether a graph is a forest

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for an authoritative source from which to cite the fact that checking whether a graph is a forest can be done in linear time with respect to the number of vertices (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2122508).
(I don't want to include my own proof because of space constraints but I also don't want to just state the fact without a citation, as my university is quite strict about plagiarism.)

The books I've consulted either just show and prove the characterisations of forests but don't present an explicit algorithm, or they do present an algorithm but not its complexity analysis.

Comment: (1) You could cite the stackexchange answer (2) What kind of space constraints rule out giving a proof that's 1-2 sentences long?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I would have to include the algorithm, or if I refer to time complexities of e.g. finding connected components I would have to write a proof for that too, and the algorithm, and so on.

Comment: Well, it should be easy to find a citation for depth-first search. You're just doing one modification to it (stop as soon as you find a cycle) and that shouldn't take long to explain.

Comment: One possibility is to refer to a linear-time algorithm for finding the connected components $\mathcal{C}$ (citing a book on graph algorithms), then to say that it is sufficient to check whether $|E| + |\mathcal{C}|= |V|$ (this can also be found in graph theory books).